# Error al insertar multiples registros en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, array, insert, model

estoy tratando de hacer un multiple insert en mysql con pdo desde php usando un ciclo for para controlar la cantidad de inserciones que quiero hacer pero no logro saber cual es la falla y este es el error que me sale 3 veces

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/casas-lotes/application/Model/Lotes.php on line 53

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO LOTES (id_tipo_lote, medidas, valor, valor_financiado, estado_lote, id_usuario, plazo_cuotas)
        VALUES(
        :id_tipo_lote,
        :medidas,
        :valor,
        :valor_financiado,
        :estado_lote,
        :id_usuario,
        :plazo_cuotas)";

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $parametros = [];

        $parametros = array();
        for ($i=1; $i <= 3 ; $i++) { 
                $parametros[] = array(
                               ':id_tipo_lote' => 1,
                               ':medidas' => 'valor de medidas',
                               ':valor' => 'valor lote numerico',
                               ':valor_financiado' => 'valor financiado lote numerico',
                               ':estado_lote' => 1,
                               ':id_usuario' => 3,
                               ':plazo_cuotas' => 'valor plazo lote numerico');
        }

        foreach ($parametros as $value) {

                
                $stmt->execute([
                    $value[':id_tipo_lote'],
                    $value[':medidas'],
                    $value[':valor'],
                    $value[':valor_financiado'],
                    $value[':estado_lote'],
                    $value[':id_usuario'],
                    $value[':plazo_cuotas']
                ]);
        }
```

Las columnas `id_tipo_lote, estado_lote y id_usuario` son valores enteros definidos en la tabla y aqui los estoy pasando también como un valor entero

INFORMACION ADICIONAL

estructura tabla en mysql
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tu forma de hacer el `execute()` no es correcta:

```
    foreach ($parametros as $value) {                
            $stmt->execute([
                $value[':id_tipo_lote'],
                $value[':medidas'],
                $value[':valor'],
                $value[':valor_financiado'],
                $value[':estado_lote'],
                $value[':id_usuario'],
                $value[':plazo_cuotas']
            ]);
    }
```

En la consulta preparada tú usaste **marcadores de `:nombre`**, significa que en el array que pasas a `execute()` los valores deben ir asociados a esos nombres, cosa que no ocurre en tu `foreach`, donde sacas los valores solos, mareando además los datos sin necesidad.

En el primer `for` ya se asociaron los valores a cada marcador de nombre, por lo que con esto debería bastar:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO LOTES (id_tipo_lote, medidas, valor, valor_financiado, estado_lote, id_usuario, plazo_cuotas)
        VALUES(
        :id_tipo_lote,
        :medidas,
        :valor,
        :valor_financiado,
        :estado_lote,
        :id_usuario,
        :plazo_cuotas)";

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        for ($i=1; $i <= 3 ; $i++) { 
                $parametros = array(
                               ':id_tipo_lote' => 1,
                               ':medidas' => 'valor de medidas',
                               ':valor' => 'valor lote numerico',
                               ':valor_financiado' => 'valor financiado lote numerico',
                               ':estado_lote' => 1,
                               ':id_usuario' => 3,
                               ':plazo_cuotas' => 'valor plazo lote numerico');
                 $stmt->execute($parametros);                
        }
```

El `execute()` ocurre dentro de ese mismo bucle. Ahí ya conoces los valores. No veo por qué intentar el `execute()` abriendo otro bucle.

Supongo que estás en un contexto de prueba, pues el bucle `for` crea tres eventuales filas con valores duplicados, esta consulta por tanto podría dar error de clave duplicada.